# Terraform: Using "count" in modules to assign static IP addresses to instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a module which uses ec2 to create a specific instance, and now I need to assign the created instances each a static IP address from a pre-defined range.

So I define a map like this:

```
#map variable to hold IP addresses
variable "dw_manager_ips" {
  default = {
      "0" = "10.31.0.10"
      "1" = "10.31.0.11"
      "2" = "10.31.0.12"
      "3" = "10.31.0.13"
      "4" = "10.31.0.14"
     }
}
```

and in my main .tf file I use the module as follows, attempting to assign a static IP address using a counter:

```
 module "ec2-hadoop-node" {
     source                      = "../modules/ec2"
     ami_id                      = "${var.dw_manager["ami"]}"
     instance_type               = "${var.dw_manager["instance_type"]}"
     aws_region                  = "${var.region}"
     availability_zone           = "eu-west-1a"
     associate_public_ip_address = true
     role                        = "dw-manager"
     env                         = "${var.environment}"
     vpc                         = "${var.vpc_id}"
     security_group_ids          =     "${var.aws_security_group_id["sg_id"]}"
    key_name                    = "${var.key_name}"
    subnet_id           = "${var.default_subnet}"
    number_of_instances = "${var.dw_manager["count"]}"
    private_ip           = "${lookup(var.dw_manager_ips,count.index)}"
 }
```

However, it seems this is not valid syntax:

```
 "module root: resource 'aws_route53_record.nodes' config: *.public_ip   is not a valid output for module ec2-hadoop-node"
```

How would I either a) do this the right way if counter is not the right method or b) work around any limitation in Terraform modules on using count if there is one?

NOTE: I can get this to work when not using modules.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You're missing the definition of your `modules/ec2` module in your question so it's going to be difficult to point out where you're going wrong as it stands.

Comment: ydaetskcoR - thanks for your response, the module definition is quit extensive, which part would you need to see ?

Comment: Full configuration: http://pastebin.com/BQAbktj2

Comment: I can't understand how your `modules/ec2` module is used there. Are you saying that pastebin is the module and you are recursively sourcing inside it (is this even possible)?

Comment: The pastebin shows the main file of module definition in ../modues/ec2/. I use these in the code  above.